# Deletion in Left Leaning Red Black Trees

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I am learning about [Left Leaning Red Black Trees](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/LLRB/LLRB.pdf).

In the deletion algorithm peresented in the paper, if the key matches for a node and the right subtree is NULL for that node, then that node is deleted. But there may be a left subtree as well which is not considered.

I am not able to understand **why would the left subtree be NULL as well**. Similar thing is done when deleting the minimum or the maximum as well. Could anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are speaking about this piece of code:

```
if (isRed(h.left))
  h = rotateRight(h);
if (key.compareTo(h.key) == 0 && (h.right == null))
  return null;
```

Here left descendant cannot be "red" because preceding code would rotate it to the right.

Also left descendant cannot be "black" because in this case there is a path to the left of `h` containing at least one "black" node while no path to the right of it has any "black" nodes. But in RB-tree the number of black nodes on every path must be the same.

This means there is no left descendant at all and node `h` is a leaf node.

In `deleteMin` function there is no need to check right sub-tree if left sub-tree is empty because no right sub-tree of LLRB tree can be greater than corresponding left sub-tree.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, it helps me understanding deleteMin.  I have another question about deleteMin of LLRB. Could you please help me about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134053/deletemin-left-leaning-read-black-tree-need-more-explanation

Answer (score -3):

There is an interesting analysis of whether left-leaning red black trees are really better or even simpler than prior implementations. The article [Left-Leaning Red Black Trees Considered Harmful](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/notes/llrb.html) waswritten by  Harvard Comp Sci professor [Eddie Kohler](http://read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/). He writes:

```
Tricky writing

Sedgewick’s paper is tricky. As of 2013, the insert section presents 2–3–4 trees as 
the default and describes 2–3 trees as a variant. The delete implementation, however,
only works for 2–3 trees. If you implement the default variant of insert and the   
only variant of delete,your tree won’t work. The text doesn’t highlight the switch 
from   2–3–4 to 2–3: not kind.
```