# deleteMin Left Leaning Red Black Tree needs more explanation

Tags: algorithm, red-black-tree

I'm reading Left Leaning Red Black Tree in algorithms 4th edition, by Robert Sedgewick. I spent several days trying to understand the deleteMin as a warmup to understanding delete and this is my final question in my head about deleteMin.

```
    public void deleteMin()
    {
        root = deleteMin(root);
        root.color = BLACK;
    }
    private Node deleteMin(Node h)
    {
        if (h.left == null) return null;
        if (!isRed(h.left) && !isRed(h.left.left))
            h = moveRedLeft(h);
        h.left = deleteMin(h.left);
        return fixUp(h);
    }
```

when h.left and h.left.left are both black, call h=moveRedLeft(h);
The question is, how can we assert that the node b is **red**, as the picture shows?

[image: moveRedLeft]

Answer (score 1):

The question is `how can we assert that the node b is red?`

The answer is simply `we don't`. In `moveRedLeft`, we simply check for the condition.

Referring to the paper [here](http://cs.princeton.edu/%7Ers/talks/LLRB/LLRB.pdf), on page 7, we have the following code:

```
private Node moveRedLeft(Node h)
{
  colorFlip(h);
  if (isRed(h.right.left))
  {
    h.right = rotateRight(h.right);
    h = rotateLeft(h);
    colorFlip(h);
  }
  return h;
}
```

Obviously, the 4th line checks if `b` is red.